# How to Parse column that have JSON Data using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, jsonlite, data-management

The figure below show is the csv file that contain dataset that have 7 variable, this dataset contain jason data at column number 3 which is *order_list* variable

[image]

My question is how to parse the jarson data in column 3 which is *order_list* variable of this dataset.

what i already do :

```
library(jsonlite)

df2 <- purrr::map(df$order_list, jsonlite::fromJSON)

str(df2)
```

[image]

the column 3 still remain as jason data.

Comment: Please don't paste data as images. It's not helpful to anybody hoping to answer your question - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As you saw, `fromJSON` returns a list. If you want it as a data.frame or tibble you can pipe its output into `as.data.frame()` or `as_tibble()`, from the `tibble` package.

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("https://us.api.iheart.com/api/v3/live-meta/stream/2501/currentTrackMeta?defaultMetadata=true")
```

Comment: `fromJSON` returns a `data.frame` if possible - `jsoncars <- toJSON(mtcars, pretty=TRUE); fromJSON(jsoncars)` for example. This doesn't look like OP's issue as you can see in their result of `str()` that they are getting character vectors returned.

Comment: Ah, good point. Missed that in the image.